# Trouble when data was read from a postgreSQL database

Tags: r, postgresql

I have a dataset in a postgreSQL database that I am reading into an R script for manipulation through ODBC connection. I realized that computations with the dataset are erroring out due to data coming as "list" rather than "numeric". When I downloaded the data to Excel (csv) first and then read into the same R script, all is well.
I tried using the following code to try to unlist and convert to numeric the column of interest, I get the error code that follows - I don't know if this is because the column has many "NULL"s and they aren't being recognized as NULL when I tried to eliminate them with the first 2 lines shown below? OR am I doing something else wrong? Is there a better way to get the data through ODBC-postgreSQL without running into this issue or correct better?

```
  all_data2 <- all_data_plant %>%
    filter(!is.na(!!rlang::sym(test_par[j])))
  
all_data2[test_par[j]] <- as.numeric(unlist(all_data2[test_par[j]]))
```

Error: Assigned data `as.numeric(unlist(all_data2[test_par[j]]))` must be compatible with existing data. x Existing data has 17661 rows. x Assigned data has 3504 rows. i Only vectors of size 1 are recycled. Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Attached a sample of the data in Excel and here is what it looks like in R:
[How the data looks in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pvYc.png)

[How the data looks in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d9sV.png)

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data to recreate the problem you are facing?

Comment: I added as images - sorry that they both say how it looks in R but in fact one is an image from Excel and the other from R. I tried toinsert a sample of the data as Excel file but couldn't manage to do that. Hope what I showed helps

Comment: Can you post the schema as well?

Answer (score 0):

Hamdi, I believe you have got your schema incorrect. I created the whole DB from scratch and was able to import the data in RStudio without any issue.

The first thing you'll need to do is follow the given schema as I've used:

[image]

Your table should look like this:
[image]

And here's the code I used to import data in RStudio:

```
library(DBI)
library(RODBCDBI)
library(odbc)
odbc <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), dsn = "PostgreSQL")

df <- dbGetQuery(odbc, 'SELECT * FROM table1')
```

```
>class(df)
[1] "data.frame"
```

And here's the output of the query:

```
              codetime water_stucco_ratio stiffening_back_slate_coat
1  2021-01-04 02:32:00             1.1017                         NA
2  2021-01-05 02:32:00             1.1059                         NA
3  2021-01-06 02:32:00                 NA                         NA
4  2021-01-07 02:32:00             1.0922                         NA
5  2021-01-08 02:32:00                 NA                         NA
6  2021-01-09 02:32:00                 NA                         NA
7  2021-01-10 02:32:00             1.1835                         NA
8  2021-01-11 02:32:00                 NA                         NA
9  2021-01-12 02:32:00             1.1454                         NA
10 2021-01-13 02:32:00                 NA                         NA
11 2021-01-14 02:32:00                 NA                         NA
12 2021-01-15 02:32:00             1.1039                         NA
13 2021-01-16 02:32:00                 NA                         NA
14 2021-01-17 02:32:00             1.1042                         NA
15 2021-01-18 02:32:00                 NA                         NA
16 2021-01-19 02:32:00                 NA                         NA
17 2021-01-20 02:32:00                 NA                         NA
   stiffening_face_slate_coat stiffening_slurry weight_dry
1                          NA                NA         NA
2                          NA                NA         NA
3                          NA              16.2         NA
4                          NA                NA         NA
5                          NA              19.2         NA
6                          NA                NA       1432
7                          NA                NA         NA
8                          NA              15.0         NA
9                          NA                NA         NA
10                         NA              15.0         NA
11                         NA                NA       1478
12                         NA                NA         NA
13                         NA              16.2         NA
14                         NA                NA         NA
15                         NA              18.0         NA
16                         NA                NA       1463
17                         NA                NA       1463
```

Note: R is going to treat `NULL` as `NA` as it treats as not a number. Now you can perform all the manipulations you want to on the data in R.

Comment: Really appreciate this detailed help. When you say "Hamdi, I believe you have got your schema incorrect" - do you mean the datatypes aren't set up right in the PostgreSQL database? I didn't create that database and it is a massive database with hundreds of thousands of datapoints added daily that's critical to operations - namely, I would have no access to changing anything there.

Comment: On the R side, this is how I am loading the same libraries except for RODBCDBI - could that be an issue? 
I am then using the following connection script (xxxx's to hide confidential login info):
dbicon <-  DBI::dbConnect( 
               odbc::odbc(),
               driver = "PostgreSQL Unicode", 
               database = "xxxxxxx", 
               server = "xxxxxxx.rds.amazonaws.com", 
               port = "5432", 
               uid = "xxxxx_quality_analyst",
               pwd = "xxxxxxxx")

Comment: After I query and check the class, this comes up:
[1]   "tbl.df"    "tbl"   "data.frame"

Hope this helps maybe further clarify how to fix the issues I am having?

Comment: @HamdiDemirci, since you do not own the DB, you won't be able to change the data types. But still, that shouldn't be a problem.  RODBCDBI shouldn't be a problem either, as you are already getting the data in R. Since I created the DB in localhost I used the syntax that you see in answer

Comment: Please post the sample output data that you are getting in R after connection is successful.

Comment: You can get the schema using `dbGetQuery(odbc, '\\d+ table1')`. Post it as well.

Comment: I tried:
dbGetQuery(dbicon, '\\d+ qds.tests')
and got error message
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42601: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\"; Error while preparing parameters RROR: syntax error at or near "\"; Error while preparing parameters <SQL> '\d+ qds.tests'

Comment: After connecting to the postgreSQL database from R and uploading data, the data is coming up as a list and I haven't been able to convert it to numeric as posted in my original description of this post - I think that's the problem but not sure. The data image is too large for this comment - I will add it as a answer to my own question.
class(all_data_db$weight_dry)
[1] "list"

Comment: Even if the query `\\d+ qds.tests')` is giving error, it will give an output. Without storing it in a variable, print it

Comment: It seems like, when I first connect to the database, I get this warning - any thoughts if this is the issue and if likely so, how to fix?
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
* Use `values_fn = list` to suppress this warning.
* Use `values_fn = length` to identify where the duplicates arise
* Use `values_fn = {summary_fun}` to summarise duplicates[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"

Answer (score 0):

After connecting to the postgreSQL from R and uploading the data, the data looks like shown in the image.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmShc.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).